# How can I make all the links in the same View row "visited" when one of them is clicked?

Tags: 6, theming, navigation, views

I have a node View with `Row style:Field` and there are several fields with links to its node (the node of the row).

When users click one of those links only the actual link clicked gets `"visited"` and the color of the link changes.

But is there any way to make all those links(to the same node) `"visited"` when users click just one of them ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You a falsifying the ux by doing this.

Comment: Because anyway those links are linked to the same node within the same row. For example, one link is the title of the node and another is something like "read more".  So when a user has already clicked the title and has seen the node I want to make the link "read more" of the same node also be visited.  So that the user will easily see that he/she has already seen that node. But if only the title is "visited" the user might click "read more" thinking that he/she has not seen that node yet. Does this make sense?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Are you sure no css rules are overriding this because any links to a page you have 'visited' show be a different color. See for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/2DCLy/

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the demo site. Yes you are right. It was just the CSS problem. I'm sorry for posting this here.

Comment: Is there any way to close this?

Comment: No problem, not sure if you can close this, if you cant see a delete link then who knows.